# Можно ли навредить http боту ?

Tags: php, безопасность, веб-сервер, защита

Можно ли навредить http боту ? 
Или использовать его в личных целях ( раз уж он пытается использовать мой web-сервер в своих целях )?

Comment: Напомнило: [https://habrahabr.ru/post/332580/](https://habrahabr.ru/post/332580/)

Comment: С чем-то подобным я однажды встречался давно. Мне эта идея тогда очень понравилась. Но это врядли поможет навредить http-спам-боту пытающемуся загрузить на сайт рекламные объявления.

Comment: Может можно, а может нельзя...

Comment: Можно. Информируйте антиспам базы (на вроде stop forum spam) о нем.